# PHP - echo entire xml string (including tags)

Tags: php, xml

I wish to include in an email the entire xml string (inlcuding headers, tags etc) as a backup to copy/paste.  If I use the following:

`<?php
    $xml_content = file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml');
    echo $xml_content;
?>`

It shows:
Tove Jani Reminder Don't forget me this weekend!

Rather than the full string which would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note> 
 <to>Tove</to> 
 <from>Jani</from> 
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: It **does** return the full XML string. If you are viewing from a browser, try to view source.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the page content type to xml or plaintext if you want it to output the file entirely.

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

or if this doesn't work, then

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: I mainly wish to import the xml and use it within PHP, will that mess that part up?

Comment: If you wish to import the XML to PHP, just do it. Your problem is  a display issue when outputting the XML document onto an HTML page. Your browser is treating the XML elements, e.g. `<note>`, as if they're (unknown) HTML elements and not showing them. The PHP will receive the XML just fine.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you want to send the XML in an email, then either you'll need to make sure the email type is plain text, or, if it's HTML, encode the XML output so it displays okay, probably using [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) That would also work for outputting it onto an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to show the XML with tags in email, then you have to convert the special HTML tags to entities.

```
<?php
    $xml_content = file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml');
    echo htmlspecialchars($xml_content);
?>
```